# exclude object from queryset in many to many relation in django

Tags: django, forms, permissions, relation

so i have a many to many relation between my own Role model and the django auth permission model, the thing is, i tried to get all permissions associated with a specific role like this role.permisos (permisos being the many to many atribute), it works ok.
Now, im looking forward to add that queryset to a form, but before that i tried to filter some permissions i don't want the user to see
i did role1.permisos.exclude(name="Can change somethings") (being role1 an instance of role) but it just dosn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with a template, add it to your context. If it's a class-based view, override the get_context_data method.
You can also do it overriding the get_initial_data method.